# Attribute can not be used when did android theme development

Tags: android, themes

I'm studying how to use custom theme in android application. After I create a style.xml, and input below xml strings.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="editTextColor">#00f</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Eclipse gave an error when I run the project, it can not find the attribute "editTextColor", but in the sdkpath\platforms\android-17\data\res\values\themes.xml, it does use "editTextColor" attribute.

When I changed the editTextColor, the application works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:editTextColor">#00f</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Can anyone tell me why please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inside **sdkpath\platforms\android-17\data\res\values\themes.xml**, it is referencing the value directly means inside android platform itself, but while you are trying to reference it inside your application you have to reference it using **android:editTextColor** because you are using it outside android platform itself and overriding its value.Hope you got some idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it maybe because that. But when I type into "android:" and use the auto complete function, it does not show android:editTextColor, just some other attributes, like "android:textColor".

Comment: but u r using in ur question android:editTextColor in second condition and if you are using it there then it must show that with autocompletion.

Comment: Eclipse support for Android XML autocompletion is quite dismal

Comment: @WeNeigh what do u mean by that ?

Comment: I get the message "Content Assist not available at the current location" a lot.

Comment: @WeNeigh that will come where u will have some error or something wrong with eclipse.else it will be available for sure.